# MongoDB how to $set & $inc by single update call?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update and increment a record. I want something like:

```
Player.updateOne({ _id: id }, 
    { $inc: { balance: y } },
    { $set:{ chip: x} },
  );
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check this.

```
Player.updateOne({ _id: id }, 
    { $inc: { balance: 1 }, $set:{ chip: x} }
-----------------------^ // increment amount
);
```

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Comment: the balance should be incrementing existing value